# Which test is the most convincing?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, dynamic-regression

Brief background: I’m examining mediation rates in China. I have a panel dataset with N=24 provinces and T=30 years (1985-2014). For each province-year, I observe mediation rates and host of economic/demographic information.

Anecdotal reports suggest that in 2006 or soon thereafter, the Chinese government began bolstering its mediation system and encouraging its use. My goal is to test this assertion. Unfortunately, I’m unable to quantify the “effort” the government exerts in promoting mediation.

What is the most convincing way to test this assertion? My ideas are listed below. Please evaluate. For all ideas, assume that I am regressing mediation rates on variables thought to influence mediation rates.

1. Include a time polynomial (such as year and year^2) in the regression. If year is negative and year^2 is positive, this is evidence of a parabolic trend, even after controlling for other factors. Proceed by determining whether the minimum of the parabola is around year 2006.
2. Include a lagged dependent variable in the regression, that is, a lag of the mediation rate. Perhaps the best measure of “effort” is the previous year’s mediation rate. After controlling for other factors, I can determine whether this effort proxy is positive and significant.
3. Include year fixed effects. After these effects are estimated, graph their magnitudes against time. Progressively increasing year fixed effects after 2006 would indicate more effort.
4. Include a linear time trend with a kink at 2006. Determine whether the post 2006 trend is significantly larger than the pre 2006 trend. Unlike the other ideas, this one assumes that we know where the change occurs.

Is there any reason to use a combination of these ideas? Do you have other ideas? Please suggest. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is a mediation rate?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Mediation rate refers to the number of civil disputes resolved through the mediation process per capita. If you want me to explain more about China's mediation process, I'm happy to do that but I don't think it's relevant to the question here.

Comment: I guess you could consider a sequence of kinks (e.g., 2005, 2006, 2007), fit the model for each of them and then compare the resulting fits on some basis to see which one is most supported by the data. Detecting where the kink occurs (assuming it occurs) is one thing - being able to ascribe that kink to government intervention (as opposed to any other factors) is another. You are going to need more than anectodal evidence to make that interpretational leap. The kink approach assumes a certain type of "intervention" effect; there are others, but all will suffer from interpretational challenges.

Comment: Hi Isabella. Thank you for the response. You're absolutely right that ascribing the change in mediation to government intervention is a leap. Without a measure of government "effort," it may be impossible. This paper is in its early stages and I'm still trying to decide on its focus. The paper is the first (that I know of) to empirically examine mediation in China and will also identify other factors connected with mediation. I wonder if these aspects coupled with the empirical suggestions (not conclusions) about government effort are enough. Any additional thoughts you have are most welcome!